# How can I move a workflow into a solution?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I've designed a workflow of many, many steps. It works perfectly and I'm very satisfied. THe problem is that when I created it, I was unfocused and put it as a customization (*new_wroom*) instead of a part of my solution (*godlike_wroom*).

One option is to re-create it by simply adding the same steps I did before to a new one, that is created within the scope of *godlike* solution. That makes me sad...

Is there a way to move the workflow into the scope of a solution (or an other solution, for that matter)?

Comment: has your question been answered?

Comment: @GregOwens Yes, thanks. I'm just forgetful. Thanks for poking me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need to be able to export your workflow exactly "as is" as part of a solution then:

Go to Customisations  > Solutions > [open your solution] > Components > Processes

Next to the "Add new" button there is an "Add Existing" button which allows you to select components from the Default Solution.

Note that this does not change the schema name of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If I read between the lines of your question I might interpret that you wish to change the schema name of the workflow before adding it into a solution. There is no supported way to do this however you can:  create a new temporary solution containing just the workflow; export as unmanaged; extract the zip; edit the customization.xml file and do a search/replace for the old schema name; repackage it as a zip. Delete the old workflow from CRM then import your revised zip.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to up and check it. My bad. To answer **your** question - yes, your reply did answer mine. Not in the way I hoped or like, though. I'll be more careful with where I put stuff and what I call it, next time. Great answer so +1, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the workflow.

Change it's type to be published as a Process **Template**. Change it's name at the same time if you think it will help you.

Re-activate as a template.

Open your supreme_being solution and create a new workflow in there for the same entity, based on the template.

You now have a clone which you can activate.

De-activate the template and delete it if you don't think you will need it again.